# To Deploy my Python machine learning model as web service

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have developed a Machine learning model in anaconda prompt using Python3 so to deploy it and to run it anywhere dynamically on GitHub or as a webservice what is the way?

I have already used Pickle command but it didn't work for me.

```
import pickle 
file_name = "cancerdetection.ipynb"
```

It didn't deploy my model as webservice.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using flask. It uses python and deploys as a web application. Here's some sample code you can try.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')

@app.route('/')
def upload_file():    
    return "hello world"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

By setting

> host="0.0.0.0"

you're deploying your application on the net by using your local machine as a server.